# Appending Materials Automatically

Tags: materials, append

I am relatively new to Blender. I come from Sketchup for modeling and Simlab Composer for rendering. In Composer there is a function to save the material palette. Then if I have a model that uses similar materials I can re-apply all of the materials in one click using the saved material file. My question is does Blender have a similar function? I figured out how to append materials, but then I have to go through and apply them. For example any material that uses nodes does not append with the nodes intact. So I have to append the node tree and then redo the material with the correct nodes. This is very tedious and time consuming. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Instead of phrasing the title/question in terms of what you think the answer is, I think it would be better to ask about the *actual* problem you are having. See the XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Thanks.

Comment: Hello :). You mentioned "Material...doesn't append with nodes intact". Are you talking about Blender materials? Because this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I think it's pretty obvious what I'm asking. Not sure how to rephrase it to meet the XY problem standards here. If it's not clear I can provide answers to questions about my post. If you don't have an answer or question perhaps refraining from commenting is the best option. I'm just looking for help here.Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jachym, thanks for the quick reply. Yes, when I append materials from another Blend file I am not getting the nodes associated with those materials. If I click on a material it just has the default Principled BSDF. The colors seem ok, but no nodes for bump, normal or roughness.